# help regarding INSERT IGNORE mysql

Tags: mysql

The query is:

```
$sql="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS prod_day(

id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
heading TEXT,
image TEXT,
text LONGTEXT,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)TYPE=InnoDB";
```

I don't want to allow any entry that is duplicate with respect to heading , image and text column altogether. At the same time I want the id column to be auto-incrementing, plz tell me how to do that. I googled the net but couldn't get any solution comprehendible to me.

thanks

Comment: Do you want to avoid duplicate on the combination of all 3 columns together? or each column itself cannot have duplicate rows?

Comment: You will have a hard time preventing duplicates as a `UNIQUE INDEX`, since the index on the `TEXT` type has a limit of [767 bytes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-indexes.html).

Comment: @The Scrum Meister , i said 'altogether' i.e. it is only when all 3 columns get matched that an entry should be considered to be duplicate  to prevent it from getting inserted again.

Comment: @sof-user Is there any reason you are storing your fields as `TEXT` instead of `VARCHAR`?

Comment: @The Scrum Meister , not so strong reason to save as text.

Answer (score 1):

> I  don't want to allow any entry that is duplicate with respect to heading , image and text column

What you want is a `UNIQUE` key on all these columns - however MySQL will only index the first 767 bytes of for each `TEXT` and `LONGTEXT` column. *(That's bytes not characters - each character will use more than one byte in the keyspace).* This means that with a `UNIQUE KEY` on `heading` two very long but distinct strings will result in a duplicate key error:

```
-- Even though the complete strings are different, MySQL isn't indexing the whole string. 
-- These two statements will result in a duplicate key error. 
INSERT INTO prod_day (heading) VALUES ('a very long string the same in the first 767 bytes ..... asdfjkl');
INSERT INTO prod_day (heading) VALUES ('a very long string the same in the first 767 bytes ..... 1234567');
```

You have a few options:

**Refactor your database schema to use smaller column types:**

```
CREATE TABLE prod_day(
 id int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 heading VARCHAR(256),
 image VARCHAR(256),
 text VARCHAR(256),
 UNIQUE (heading, image, text)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

If that's not an option then:

**Use MD5 hashes of column data for UNIQUE keys**

```
CREATE TABLE prod_day(
 id int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 heading TEXT,
 image TEXT,
 text LONGTEXT,
 heading_md5 VARCHAR(50),
 image_md5 VARCHAR(50),
 text_md5 VARCHAR(50),
 UNIQUE (heading_md5, image_md5, text_md5)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Then, either have your PHP script calculate the md5 hash of the text fields or have MySQL do it as in the following:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO prod_day
 (heading, image, `text`, heading_md5, image_md5, text_md5)
VALUES (
 'HEADING Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ... truncated ...',
 'IMAGE Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ... truncated ...',
 'TEXT Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ... truncated ...',
 MD5('HEADING Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ... truncated ...'),
 MD5('IMAGE Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ... truncated ...'),
 MD5('TEXT Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ... truncated ...')
);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

INSERT IGNORE INTO prod_day
 (heading, image, `text`, heading_md5, image_md5, text_md5)
VALUES (
 'HEADING Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ... truncated ...',
 'IMAGE Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ... truncated ...',
 'TEXT Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ... truncated ...',
 MD5('HEADING Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ... truncated ...'),
 MD5('IMAGE Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ... truncated ...'),
 MD5('TEXT Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ... truncated ...')
);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)  -- 0 rows, duplicate avoided!
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set a `UNIQUE` constraint on the required columns
something like:

```
ALTER TABLE prod_day ( UNIQUE 'UKey_name' (`heading`,`image`,`text`));
```

EDIT: maybe some issues with your column types as Scrum Meister has pointed out. You will need to rectify this, or do it manually before inserting.

Comment: `UNIQUE` indexes don't work that way on `TEXT/BLOB` columns: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-indexes.html